# How to add up column data values when using GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am working with data from a utility company.  I have a table that contains sales records for the customers.  Each sales record has a Customer Number, Sale Date, Sales Document Number, and Sales Amount.  There is only one record for each Sales Document Number.  The Sales Amount has been computed from a second table that contains the daily usage (CCF's) for the customer during the month.  The two tables are JOINED by the Sales Document Number.  I need to summarize the daily usage into one total.  The summary should include all of the columns listed above, plus the total usage.  Here is a sample of data.

```
Table A

CustomerNumber       Date        SalesDocNumber      Amount

15422                06/14/2012    123-UTL-23001     $112.25
13784                12/07/2007    854-UTL-14096     $75.11
```

and

```
Table B

SalesDocNumber        CCF
123-UTL-23001         25.45
123-UTL-23001         118
123-UTL-23001         56.10
854-UTL-14096         10.65
854-UTL-14096         15
854-UTL-14096         13
854-UTL-14096         22.75
854-UTL-14096         31
```

This is my query

```
SELECT A.CustomerNumber,
       A.Date,
       A.SalesDocNumber,
       A.Amount
       B.CCF
FROM Table A INNER JOIN Table B ON A.SalesDocNumber = B.SalesDocNumber
GROUP BY A.CustomerNumber, A. Date, A.SalesDocNumber, A. Amount, B.CCF
```

My results show a line for each record in Table B rather than having them summarized into one line.

Expected results are

```
15422    06/14/2012   123-UTL-23001  $112.25  199.55
13784    12/07/2001   854-UTL-14096  $75.11   92.40
```

Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT A.CustomerNumber,
       A.Date,
       A.SalesDocNumber,
       A.Amount
       B.CCF
FROM TableA A
INNER JOIN (SELECT SalesDocNumber, SUM(CCF) AS CCF FROM TableB GROUP BY SalesDocNumber) B
ON A.SalesDocNumber = B.SalesDocNumber
```